# Compare two columns and print the same value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare two columns and if any similar value is there then I want to print that value in a third column. My code is like this:

```
Sub compare()

    Dim arr1 As Range
    Dim arr2 As Range

    Set arr1 = Range("A1:A6")
    Set arr2 = Range("B1:B6")

    For Each x In arr1
        For Each y In arr2
            If x = y Then
                Cells(C1).Value = 0
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

I am seeing:

> Run Time error 1004 Application-defined or object defined error

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky to use `For Each` when working with an array as you don't know where is in your array the data you are trying to work with. And furthermore, it'll only create duplicate values and you won't be able to interact with your array directly.

Plus, as your loops were sets, you would compare each cell in the first array to each one in the second array. You only need a common factor to loop on.

I added a few tests to avoid some basic issues :

```
Sub compare()
    Dim arr1 As Range, _
        arr2 As Range, _
        Ws As Worksheet
With Ws
    Set arr1 = .Range("A1:A6")
    Set arr2 = .Range("B1:B6")

    If arr1.Columns.Count > 1 Or arr2.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Too many columns for this simple compare", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If arr1.Rows.Count <> arr2.Rows.Count Or arr1.Cells(1, 1).Row <> arr2.Cells(1, 1).Row Then
            MsgBox "The ranges don't have the same amout of lines or don't start at the same line", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        Else
            For i = 1 To arr1.Rows.Count
                If arr1.Cells(i, 1) <> arr2.Cells(i, 1) Then
                Else
                    .Cells(arr1.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, _
                        Max(arr1.Cells(1, 1).Columns, arr2.Cells(1, 1).Column)) _
                            .Offset(0, 1).Value = arr1.Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you need to specify Row and Column  when using Cells. The column is 3 for column C so the code to display the matching values should have looked something like this:-

```
Sub compare()

    Dim arr1 As Range
    Dim arr2 As Range
    Dim count As Integer

    Set arr1 = Range("A1:A6")
    Set arr2 = Range("B1:B6")

    For Each x In arr1
        For Each y In arr2
            If x = y Then
                count = count + 1
                Cells(count, 3) = x
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below one easy way, define one array with one range with 3 columns (two to compare and the 3th to write result)

```
Sub compare()
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range("A1:C6")
Dim R As Long
For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    If Arr(R, 1) = Arr(R, 2) Then
        Arr(R, 3) = 0 'or the value of 1th column like arr(r,1)
    End If
Next R
Range("A1:C6") = Arr
End Sub
```